# Setting text color and size in android listview

Tags: android, string, listview, spannablestring

I'm trying to set the text size and color for strings inside of a ListView in Android.  Using spannable strings to reach this goal.  Here's my code (from onCreate):

```
statusInfo = new String[jArray.length()];

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusInfo);
        formList.setAdapter(adapter);

SpannableStringBuilder secondPart = new SpannableStringBuilder("Status: " + formStatus + " - Window: " + formWindowStart + " - " + formWindowEnd);

            int cs_blue = getResources().getColor(R.color.cs_blue);
            int green = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);


            if(fs == -1)
            {
                ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(cs_blue);
                secondPart.setSpan(fcs, 0, secondPart.length(), 0);
            }
            if(fs == 1)
            {
                ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(green);
                secondPart.setSpan(fcs, 0, secondPart.length(), 0);
            }


            //need text size of 12...85.714% of 14
            secondPart.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.85714f), 0, secondPart.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The problem is that the text is still black and normal size.  Do not know why its not changing the size and color.  I looked a few other questions, but could still not get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: is that code inside getView of your adapter class right?

Comment: It's in my OnCreate.  Was trying to populate the list and do all of the color and size changing there.

Comment: Hmm looks right to me. Where do you set `secondPart` to a TextView?

Comment: I was under the belief that I didn't need a TextView.  Thought could just color and size each string that goes into the ListView.  Maybe that's the problem.  Currently I combine firstPart (not shown) and secondPart and then put that into statusInfo as an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I've got your problem.

You can take a look at the [Sourcecode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) of TextView.

What you need is:

1. Your Text is recognized as Spannable, so that the differenz Styles can be applied
2. Your View must be updated

Both happens in `setText`.
So if you what to change the Style, the easiest way in my opinion is to use setText.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml simply set the

```
android:textColor="#ff0000"
android:textSize="10dp" // 10sp
```

just an example